# X-Men Comics: Battle of the Atom Reading Order

Tags: marvel, x-men, suggested-order

I have all the *All-New X-Men* and *Uncanny X-Men (Vol 3)* comics including the 10 issue event "Battle of the Atom".

**Question**: What is the correct reading order? When do I start the "Battle of the Atom" event with respect to the story lines of *All-New X-Men* and *Uncanny*? I want to stay true to the story as much as I can. Do I read each series one at a time or do they overlap at any time before the event?

I'm 7 issues deep into *All-New X-Men* and every website I go to tells me something different. One website told me *A+X* was after *All-New X-Men* so I bought all them only to find out they had nothing to do with the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to read *All-New* and *Uncanny* in chronological order you need to know when each began: **[All-New X-Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-New_X-Men)** debuted in November 2012 while **[Uncanny X-Men (vol 3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men#2013-present:_Volume_3)** debuted in February 2013.

Which puts *All-New* three issues ahead, but the first two issues of *All-New* came out within the same month (to whet our appetite). So when you finish issue 4 of *All-New* you should begin *Uncanny*... I think the break there in *Uncanny* was because MARVEL wanted us to read the [Five issue mini-series **AvX: Consequences**](http://marvel.com/comics/series/16510/avx_consequences_2012) as a prequel to the new **Uncanny X-Men** series.

I read them all as they came out, I would read an issue of *All-New* followed by that month's issue of *Uncanny*, which is how I recommend reading them unless so noted within the issue itself.

Here's the reading order of **Battle for the Atom** which you already know from the numbering on the issues but I figured *what the heck!*  **PLUS** who doesn't love seeing Arthur Adams' X-Men:
[image]

Comment: thank u sir what was throwing me off was when to read the xmen battle of the atom chapter 1 001,the rest of the battle of the atoms books was easy to fill in the blanks it was just the xmen titles in the group like (part 1 part 3 and part 7)but again thank u for the info and u taughter me sumthing new i didnt kno aVx was a prequel to uncanny xmen,so i would read the 1st 4 books of all new xmen then read all of aVX before i start uncanny ?