# X-men Reading Order EDIT

Tags: marvel, x-men, suggested-order

I know this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the answer that I want. I want to read the X-men comics in order - the teams, the storylines, what happened when. For example, I've read about the split into two different groups after Xavier's death, but I want to read everything that made that happen. Any everything else in the universe.

Right now, I'm working on Volume 1 of the original Uncanny X-men, to be followed by Volumes 2 and 3. Since The New Mutants was introduced in this arc, I think I should read it next? But when do I read Astonishing X-men, or X-factor, or anything else? Does anyone have a list of some sort of where everything is supposed to go? I know, this is probably a hard question, but I just want a timeline of which titles I should read in order.

I guess I just need a title/group of characters timeline.

Thanks if anyone can help.

EDIT_ For all of those links given, I've already tried those. If they had what I needed, I wouldn't have bothered to post this question. As stated before, I've already started reading Uncanny X-Men. I want to read all of the comics. I just want to know the titles that I need to go by. For example, I think that New Mutants should be read next since it was published at the same time? Or am I wrong? Also, the Wikipedia article was only confusing; it just talked about story arcs, characters involved, which didn't help me in working out the different title order. **Easy question: Titles in order, all X-men issues after Uncanny X-men**

. Any help out there? (Not to be angry, but I knew about all of those other posts before I asked my question. I know to look before I randomly post crap that's been answered a hundred times.)

Comment: "two different groups after Xavier's death" after which death? the number of times he's "died" is pretty ridiculous.

Comment: is [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51990/x-men-comics-reading-order) what you're after?

Comment: Or [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46239/in-what-order-should-i-read-the-x-men-comics), perhaps?

Comment: “I guess I just need a title/group of characters timeline.” Yup. Just that. Pretty simple really, the [X-Men have only been going since 1963](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men#Publication_history). (In case that sounded snarky, this is a good question, and I hope you find a good answer.)

Comment: Just to clarify — you want to read every X-Men comic, from the very beginning?

Comment: If you're concerned with continuity, you can't just read all of New Mutants next - you have to read every issue in the order they were published - making sure to read all the related titles.